# ASP.NET Core Runtime deploymenet CERTIFICATES TRUST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, https, ssl-certificate

I am deploying my API (ASP.NET Core 3.1) to a server and I am listening on **https** url only:

```
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000;https://*:5001");
```

But I am getting and error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
```

In deployement, you make your self-signed ceritifate with:

```
...
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
...
```

But I cannot use it ofcourse because I have only runtime .Net Core and not SDK and it should be deployed app.

I have certificate file and key **ssl.crt** and **ssl.key** which I am using in my frontends apps (apache settings etc etc... you know what I mean).

Can I use it in ASP.NET or how do I do it?

Thanks

Comment: "I have certificate file and key ssl.crt and ssl.key which I am using in my frontends apps (apache settings etc etc... you know what I mean)." Then why not run your ASP.NET Core app HTTP only, and use Apache as reverse proxy to take care of HTTPS for it? Typical usage of Apache which you can learn everywhere.

Comment: I have web app, which is using the API, but when I am trying to do HTTP request, it will throw an exception that from https web you cannot call http request. Hmm, I dont know I understand you properly what you mean, can you send me some example?

Comment: I wonder how much you know about Apache. Otherwise, what I commented above should be more than enough to get started. Reverse proxy is the way to allow external callers (web/desktop/mobile) to call `https://some.site` on Apache, while the actual requests are passed on to `http://localhost:5000` and processed by your ASP.NET Core app. In that way, none of the caller needs to know the real localhost address. Learn about Apache further please.

Comment: Yeah, I understand proxy. I will try to set it up. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: BTW, you really need to modify your ASP.NET Core app to remove the default HTTP to HTTPS redirection, or run it with `--urls http://localhost:5000`. That's what caused the exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

So as you can see in comments above (under question), there was a tip from Lex Li to listen on `http://` and use proxyreverse to redirect https calls onto http.

But to be honest, this solution is little bit shady and I did not want to do it that way, so I continued my searching and found NuGet [LettuceEncrypt](https://github.com/natemcmaster/LettuceEncrypt) which is actually solving my problem. I can now listen `https` calls, I dont need to use some shady solution with proxyreverse and also I dont have to install whole SDK to use `dotnet dev-certs` commands.

On github page I sent before is sample usage with 2 sample applications, so if you have similar problem, take a look at it and maybe it will wolve the problem for you too.